# Django rest with raw

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

sorry I have a problem with raw, I'm trying to add up the total sales for each month, but I have an error.
this is my sight.

```
class TotalSale(ListAPIView):
      serializer_class = TotalSaleSerealizer
      def get_queryset(self):
          queryset = Sale.objects.raw("SELECT 1 id, SUM(totalprice), 
          to_char(datesale,'yyyy-MM') FROM sales_sale group by 
          to_char(datesale,'yyyy-MM')")
          return queryset
```

the to_char I am using to change the format of my date and so I can calculate the sales of each month, this query works well when I do it directly in Postgresql, but when I do it in django I do not vote for the correct data.

```
1,'1197','2018-10'
1,'612','2018-09'
1,'1956','2018-08'
```

and it's fine I calculate the sum of the sales of each month
But when I do that in Django, this comes to me.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "totalprice": 144,
    "datesale": "2018-08-06"
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "totalprice": 144,
    "datesale": "2018-08-06"
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "totalprice": 144,
    "datesale": "2018-08-06"
}
```

I think the error is for the 1 id, just filter the data of the data that has id 1, my question is why that happens, how can I solve it try to remove the 1 id but another error comes out, how can I fix that problem.

Comment: The code you provided looks working. The issue is likely in other part of the code you didn't pasted here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the rest is irrelevant, because the view is the most important, but here is the remaining code.

```
class TotalSaleSerealizer(ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = Sale
            fields = ('id','totalprice', 'datesale')


class Sale(models.Model):
    id_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null =False, blank=False, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null =False, blank=False, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datesale = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    totalprice = models.IntegerField()
```

these are the serealizer and the model